# AWS EC2 disk full, cannot release space

Tags: server, disk-usage, amazon-ec2

I am using an EC2 instance to run a node app. I logged into the server after a while only to realise that the server has run out of disk space. After debugging, I realised that logs are taking up space. I deleted the 3.3Gb log file. However, even after the cleanup there is no space. What should I do?

Here are the commands I ran:

```
ubuntu@app1:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            488M     0  488M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs           496M  8.0K  496M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

---

```
ubuntu@app1:~$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / | sort -n
0   /proc
0   /sys
4.0K    /lib64
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /srv
8.0K    /dev
8.0K    /snap
16K /lost+found
24K /root
800K    /tmp
6.4M    /etc
11M /run
14M /sbin
16M /bin
246M    /boot
331M    /home
397M    /opt
429M    /var
538M    /lib
2.1G    /usr
3.7G    /data
7.7G    /
```

I deleted a 3.3G log file in `/data` and ran `du` again

```
ubuntu@app1:~$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / | sort -h
0   /proc
0   /sys
4.0K    /lib64
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /srv
8.0K    /dev
8.0K    /snap
16K /lost+found
24K /root
800K    /tmp
6.4M    /etc
11M /run
14M /sbin
16M /bin
246M    /boot
331M    /home
352M    /data
397M    /opt
429M    /var
538M    /lib
2.1G    /usr
4.4G    /
```

---

```
ubuntu@app1:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            488M     0  488M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs           496M  8.0K  496M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

**Although the `/data` directory is now reduced to 352M, still `df` still shows 100% disk utilization. What am I missing?**

Referring to this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253655/47050, here is the output of `strace`

```
ubuntu@app1:~$ strace -e statfs df /
statfs("/", {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=2016361, f_bfree=4096, f_bavail=0, f_files=1024000, f_ffree=617995, f_fsid={2136106470, -680157247}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=4128}) = 0
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       8065444 8049060         0 100% /
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

=

After running `sync && sync && sync`, 
 `df -h` still shows

```
/dev/xvda1 7.7G 7.7G 0 100% /.
```

But `sudo du -h` shows 4.4G

=

Then ran `sudo lsof | grep deleted` and found many lines like

```
node\x20/ 22318 deploy 12w REG 202,1 3541729280 791684 /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
```

How do I release these files?

Answer (score 1):

Run `sync && sync && sync`

Comment: Ran this command. Still `df -h` shows `/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /`. But `sudo du -h` shows `4.4G /`

Comment: I ran `sudo lsof | grep deleted` and found many lines like `node\x20/ 22318           deploy   12w      REG              202,1 3541729280     791684 /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)`

Comment: How do I release these files

Comment: FYI,  Add Comment is our channel to you; please avoid using Add Comment. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit] which is your channel to us. You new findings are now added into the question.